# Matplotlib - how to break y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, axis, break

Actually, I have been trying, but I could not figure out how it works according to my plot code.
I am trying to break the y-axis between (190 and 390), but I can't figure out how to accomplish this with the current code. I would appreciate some help!

Per the photo [image], I explained where the break should be and my current plot illustration.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# include if using a Jupyter notebook
# %matplotlib inline

# Calculate 
P1_R1= np.array([133.99993318107406, 131.18684926667854, 135.02452811754503, 133.7042841570604, 135.50609470221127])
P2_R1=np.array([413.523519750599, 416.84725331204925, 408.5133417315719, 410.6699154442544, 408.7185250820563])
P3_R1=np.array([497.6854297477017, 491.4875943176364, 490.8336665008912, 496.12836704514336, 505.6797222125371])
P4_R1= np.array([124.51037185100775, 103.89814858392904, 100.72147200922687, 101.24290612897902, 104.68560122212921])
P5_R1=np.array([112.90028855356645, 123.79089725459612, 115.69806381675994, 108.64940645571004, 118.19210579797077])
P6_R1=np.array([419.2434662756869, 441.7227209203235, 436.6211991130073, 431.76023120929347, 442.0194266206212])
P7_R1= np.array([176.04916592561875, 171.19587226771304, 174.24380385828724, 176.3034069402004, 175.01585123959075])
P8_R1=np.array([112.0722353683995, 111.3481443448815, 111.20894158213548, 110.76715598807796, 111.55404034530706])
P9_R1=np.array([84.8154591243869, 88.648758090197, 84.00783449555973, 86.71396926641148, 84.34514791037478])
P10_R1=np.array([398.4921946025974, 398.88514815464515, 406.22897428743016, 399.50893021351453, 400.8880181972834])
# Calculate
P1_R1_a= np.array([6.351167920172815, 5.879345456142222, 2.39260473383481, 0.979994558971595, 2.880162956383151])
P2_R1_a=np.array([4.1414182354129565, 3.830579727728624, 3.3442537436100346, 6.627647779177809, 4.741015486516087])
P3_R1_a=np.array([1.92215740851005, 1.611866857439105, 2.8681922657423957, 5.728518942512359, 1.116787873996628])
P4_R1_a= np.array([6.015523655706968, 2.9546990100086705, 13.675829257937137, 3.6209014285128878, 10.619255144571943])
P5_R1_a=np.array([2.1309606729918116, 31.605624673733804, 9.439155161740462, 4.465930151082304, 3.820418577801154])
P6_R1_a=np.array([5.13797710769113, 2.414152725747402, 5.175893717413631, 2.9793423938248864, 9.551150555122236])
P7_R1_a= np.array([0.6067772397737916, 5.7463993532278295, 1.9824467919584676, 3.1589542344710853, 1.6886401070000836])
P8_R1_a=np.array([10.040196906711317, 1.1343590539543156, 1.150537673246555, 2.250148905868831, 0.6147076476749518])
P9_R1_a=np.array([3.9824156407735845, 5.4140440543888255, 8.645134595880744, 5.107826414392328, 4.05661846256759])
P10_R1_a=np.array([2.2475647302788033, 1.0465483956763428, 3.2404867402663613, 2.750575203546946, 2.902862618034883])
# Calculate 
P1_R2=np.array([136.81130137813162, 139.38576158622672, 138.42647394407956, 131.6466048955989, 131.5177929164115])
P2_R2=np.array([407.12551322669515, 405.9453752158412, 416.5853915527993, 416.8401373871095, 405.91255363336285])
P3_R2=np.array([490.2170736387452, 491.981410686253, 498.39770888141794, 480.1651981030459, 507.27724181302295])
P4_R2= np.array([123.25669831593403, 118.1518121253839, 100.51783063515333, 97.37433963315705, 103.70331904189011])
P5_R2=np.array([112.43858352360752, 120.7698670659671, 113.73903527245683, 116.75114171673796, 124.90735642367567])
P6_R2=np.array([439.92006779934354, 431.36638513500753, 430.1811092261483, 443.70699312614437, 441.58403476722555])
P7_R2= np.array([172.25544790827155, 178.24737100147618, 166.39844711738607, 172.3116682826334, 176.27769536345087])
P8_R2=np.array([112.33935493533662, 104.74069653038865, 112.09322247985232, 100.21244347063778, 116.99457896486521])
P9_R2=np.array([90.34369941562457, 82.89288846810247, 86.49563408919728, 96.25809975579091, 92.28045716351546])
P10_R2=np.array([404.9254501682259, 403.0097628256805, 416.7857576775345, 401.1894405599885, 413.8048437830903])
# Calculate
P1_R2_a= np.array([2.0898677232212908, 1.5272418777112269, 3.3533946268047816, 2.193277559501947, 1.5664798424036752])
P2_R2_a=np.array([1.162425236367175, 1.158932366451874, 1.9079130424507993, 1.793579250359063, 2.105472349819792])
P3_R2_a=np.array([0.9162151373877989, 1.6196946107751526, 2.214479081545268, 7.262805672491402, 1.1716780052487135])
P4_R2_a= np.array([1.733696631601097, 15.080620264903926, 0.9717423678931834, 1.2209477095382044, 1.3063117465073464])
P5_R2_a=np.array([3.8966435629421667, 3.0696868480881756, 4.748512388149633, 4.0617028597393325, 2.3087646567304363])
P6_R2_a=np.array([0.4468490223500979, 0.4460699274552764, 0.7883847450188307, 0.3985956203234417, 1.2933150346440279])
P7_R2_a= np.array([1.7331104818867265, 2.4709473750277438, 2.1312549551991196, 0.7101929710230714, 1.8823564767751753])
P8_R2_a=np.array([1.5877750216887567, 1.6147990102250607, 1.1960434529871367, 1.7251064652057475, 1.0625656108540584])
P9_R2_a=np.array([0.9860482287666764, 3.5070302596785887, 1.6736350219768863, 3.7739314672616278, 5.525608804975998])
P10_R2_a=np.array([1.4982281205575296, 4.778343188067102, 0.808936425370139, 1.199406763048095, 1.0858369821875695])
# Calculate the mean
P1_R1_mean = np.mean(P1_R1)
P2_R1_mean = np.mean(P2_R1)
P3_R1_mean = np.mean(P3_R1)
P4_R1_mean = np.mean(P4_R1)
P5_R1_mean = np.mean(P5_R1)
P6_R1_mean = np.mean(P6_R1)
P7_R1_mean = np.mean(P7_R1)
P8_R1_mean = np.mean(P8_R1)
P9_R1_mean = np.mean(P9_R1)
P10_R1_mean = np.mean(P10_R1)
# Calculate the standard deviation
P1_R1_std =np.std(P1_R1)
P2_R1_std =np.std(P2_R1)
P3_R1_std =np.std(P3_R1)
P4_R1_std =np.std(P4_R1)
P5_R1_std =np.std(P5_R1)
P6_R1_std =np.std(P6_R1)
P7_R1_std =np.std(P7_R1)
P8_R1_std =np.std(P8_R1)
P9_R1_std =np.std(P9_R1)
P10_R1_std =np.std(P10_R1)
# Calculate the mean
P1_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P1_R1_a)
P2_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P2_R1_a)
P3_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P3_R1_a)
P4_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P4_R1_a)
P5_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P5_R1_a)
P6_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P6_R1_a)
P7_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P7_R1_a)
P8_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P8_R1_a)
P9_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P9_R1_a)
P10_R1_a_mean = np.mean(P10_R1_a)
# Calculate the standard deviation
P1_R1_a_std =np.std(P1_R1_a)
P2_R1_a_std =np.std(P2_R1_a)
P3_R1_a_std =np.std(P3_R1_a)
P4_R1_a_std =np.std(P4_R1_a)
P5_R1_a_std =np.std(P5_R1_a)
P6_R1_a_std =np.std(P6_R1_a)
P7_R1_a_std =np.std(P7_R1_a)
P8_R1_a_std =np.std(P8_R1_a)
P9_R1_a_std =np.std(P9_R1_a)
P10_R1_a_std =np.std(P10_R1_a)
# Calculate the mean
P1_R2_mean = np.mean(P1_R2)
P2_R2_mean = np.mean(P2_R2)
P3_R2_mean = np.mean(P3_R2)
P4_R2_mean = np.mean(P4_R2)
P5_R2_mean = np.mean(P5_R2)
P6_R2_mean = np.mean(P6_R2)
P7_R2_mean = np.mean(P7_R2)
P8_R2_mean = np.mean(P8_R2)
P9_R2_mean = np.mean(P9_R2)
P10_R2_mean = np.mean(P10_R2)
# Calculate the standard deviation
P1_R2_std =np.std(P1_R2)
P2_R2_std =np.std(P2_R2)
P3_R2_std =np.std(P3_R2)
P4_R2_std =np.std(P4_R2)
P5_R2_std =np.std(P5_R2)
P6_R2_std =np.std(P6_R2)
P7_R2_std =np.std(P7_R2)
P8_R2_std =np.std(P8_R2)
P9_R2_std =np.std(P9_R2)
P10_R2_std =np.std(P10_R2)

# Calculate the average
P1_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P1_R2_a)
P2_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P2_R2_a)
P3_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P3_R2_a)
P4_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P4_R2_a)
P5_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P5_R2_a)
P6_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P6_R2_a)
P7_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P7_R2_a)
P8_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P8_R2_a)
P9_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P9_R2_a)
P10_R2_a_mean = np.mean(P10_R2_a)
# Calculate the standard deviation
P1_R2_a_std =np.std(P1_R2_a)
P2_R2_a_std =np.std(P2_R2_a)
P3_R2_a_std =np.std(P3_R2_a)
P4_R2_a_std =np.std(P4_R2_a)
P5_R2_a_std =np.std(P5_R2_a)
P6_R2_a_std =np.std(P6_R2_a)
P7_R2_a_std =np.std(P7_R2_a)
P8_R2_a_std =np.std(P8_R2_a)
P9_R2_a_std =np.std(P9_R2_a)
P10_R2_a_std =np.std(P10_R2_a)

# Define labels, positions, bar heights and error bar heights
labels = ['P1','P2','P3', 'P4', 'P5','P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10']
x_pos = np.arange(len(labels))
CTEs1 = [P1_R1_mean, P2_R1_mean, P3_R1_mean,P4_R1_mean, P5_R1_mean, P6_R1_mean,P7_R1_mean, P8_R1_mean, P9_R1_mean, P10_R1_mean]
error1 = [P1_R1_std, P2_R1_std, P3_R1_std,P4_R1_std,P5_R1_std,P6_R1_std,P7_R1_std,P8_R1_std,P9_R1_std,P10_R1_std]
CTEs2 = [P1_R1_a_mean, P2_R1_a_mean, P3_R1_a_mean,P4_R1_a_mean, P5_R1_a_mean, P6_R1_a_mean,P7_R1_a_mean, P8_R1_a_mean, P9_R1_a_mean, P10_R1_a_mean]
error2 = [P1_R1_a_std, P2_R1_a_std, P3_R1_a_std,P4_R1_a_std,P5_R1_a_std,P6_R1_a_std,P7_R1_a_std,P8_R1_a_std,P9_R1_a_std,P10_R1_a_std]
CTEs3 = [P1_R2_mean, P2_R2_mean, P3_R2_mean,P4_R2_mean, P5_R2_mean, P6_R2_mean,P7_R2_mean, P8_R2_mean, P9_R2_mean, P10_R2_mean]
error3 = [P1_R2_std, P2_R2_std, P3_R2_std,P4_R2_std,P5_R2_std,P6_R2_std,P7_R2_std,P8_R2_std,P9_R2_std,P10_R2_std]
CTEs4 = [P1_R2_a_mean, P2_R2_a_mean, P3_R2_a_mean,P4_R2_a_mean, P5_R2_a_mean, P6_R2_a_mean,P7_R2_a_mean, P8_R2_a_mean, P9_R2_a_mean, P10_R2_a_mean]
error4 = [P1_R2_a_std, P2_R2_a_std, P3_R2_a_std,P4_R2_a_std,P5_R2_a_std,P6_R2_a_std,P7_R2_a_std,P8_R2_a_std,P9_R2_a_std,P10_R2_a_std]

# Build the plot
labels = ['P1','P2','P3', 'P4', 'P5','P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10']
x_pos = np.arange(len(labels))
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(20, 11)
fig.savefig('test2png.png', dpi=100)
ax.bar(x_pos-.3, CTEs1, 
       yerr=error1,
         alpha=0.5,
       ecolor='black',
       capsize=10, label='Rater 1_before', width=.2)
ax.bar(x_pos-.1, CTEs2, 
       yerr=error2,
         alpha=0.5,
       ecolor='black',
       capsize=10, label='Rater 1_after', width=.2)
ax.bar(x_pos+0.1, CTEs3,
       yerr=error3,
         alpha=0.5,
       ecolor='black',
       capsize=10, label='Rater 2_before', width=.2)
ax.bar(x_pos+.3, CTEs4, 
       yerr=error4,
         alpha=0.5,
       ecolor='black',
       capsize=10, label='Rater 2_after', width=.2)


#ax.brokenaxes(xlims=((0, 5), (7, 10)),ylims=((0, 200), (400, 550)), hspace=.015)

ax.set_ylabel('Target Registration Error TRE (mm)',fontsize=22)
ax.set_xlabel('Patient No.',fontsize=22)
ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_title('Quantitative evaluation with mean and standard deviation',fontsize=22, pad=20)
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
ax.legend(fontsize=18,bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc='upper right', borderaxespad=0.9)

#ax = brokenaxes(xlims=((P1,P3),(P5,P8)), ylims=((0,190),(390,550)), hspace=.1) 


#ax.set_axisbelow(True)
#ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
#ax.set_ylim(400, 550)  # outliers only
#ax.set_ylim(0, 200)  # most of the data
# Save the figure and show




plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('bar_plot_with_error_bars.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: why do you need the break? Don't you think that would distort the graph and become misleading?

Comment: Because I want the data to be shown below between (0 and 10 in y-axis) which did not appear clearly

Comment: then I suggest you keep this graph, and generate another one with y-axis range 0 to 10 only (to zoom in the area of interest)

Comment: Actually I want to try to generate both with a break y-axis and also with another with y-axis range 0 to 10 only (to zoom into the range of interest). The second, which is your suggestion, I will also post it as well, I have zoomed into the area of interest, but I do not figure out how to connect original figure with its part (zoomed into the area of interest)

Answer (score 2):

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/brokenaxes/

You can use `brokenaxes` library to accomplish this. Notice that `plt.tight_layout()` will not work properly with `brokenaxes`.

You can manually adjust the cut-off range for the y-axis you want in `bax = brokenaxes(ylims=((y_starting, y_break_point_1), (y_break_point_2, y_ending)), hspace=0.25)`. `hspace` controls the visual distance between `y_break_point_1` and `y_break_point_2`.

```
# data sections are excluded

from brokenaxes import brokenaxes

bax = brokenaxes(ylims=((0, 20), (390, 510)), hspace=0.25)

bax.bar(x_pos - .3, CTEs1,
        yerr=error1,
        alpha=0.5,
        ecolor='black',
        capsize=10, label='Rater 1_before', width=.2)
bax.bar(x_pos - .1, CTEs2,
        yerr=error2,
        alpha=0.5,
        ecolor='black',
        capsize=10, label='Rater 1_after', width=.2)
bax.bar(x_pos + 0.1, CTEs3,
        yerr=error3,
        alpha=0.5,
        ecolor='black',
        capsize=10, label='Rater 2_before', width=.2)
bax.bar(x_pos + .3, CTEs4,
        yerr=error4,
        alpha=0.5,
        ecolor='black',
        capsize=10, label='Rater 2_after', width=.2)

bax.set_ylabel('Target Registration Error TRE (mm)', fontsize=22)
bax.set_xlabel('Patient No.', fontsize=22)
bax.set_title('Quantitative evaluation with mean and standard deviation', fontsize=22, pad=20)
bax.legend(fontsize=18, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper right', borderaxespad=0.9)
bax.grid(axis='y', which='major', ls='-')

bax.axs[1].set_xticks(x_pos)
bax.axs[1].set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.savefig('bar_plot_with_error_bars.png')
plt.show()
```

##### Result of `bax = brokenaxes(ylims=((0, 20), (390, 510)), hspace=0.25)`

##### (this might be a bad idea since some data were cut off; only for demonstration purposes):

[image]

##### Result of `bax = brokenaxes(ylims=((0, 190), (390, 510)), hspace=0.25)`:

[image]

Comment: You can also consider using the log scale if some data are too small to observe.

Comment: Just x-axis it should be like that= P1 P2 P3... and so on.

Comment: @Fadil Fixed. Added `bax.axs[1].set_xticks(x_pos)` and `bax.axs[1].set_xticklabels(labels)`. And removed `bax.set_xticks(x_pos)` and `bax.set_xticklabels(labels)`.