# How to enlarge a part of the figure and insert it on top of the same plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, zooming, magnification

I would like to zoom a portion of data/image and plot it on top of the same figure.

I want to zoom in the shape all over the x-axis and from -3 to 15 in the y-axis.
And put the zoomed one on the top of original figure, with connect them to describe the zoomed area related to which area in original figure.

Also attached the full figure plot and a portion of it as images.[image: the full figure plot][image: a portion of it]

The full code for this graph is here

[Matplotlib - how to break y-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74950884/matplotlib-how-to-break-y-axis)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-zoom-inset-axes-py

Comment: Actually, I tried several times with similar codes related to zooming from it and putting it in the original graph, but I can't set it in my code.<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74950884/matplotlib-how-to-break-y-axis>

Comment: Not clear what issue you are having so very unclear how to help

Comment: It has been solved by  @Econlover as per the comments below

Comment: Perhaps mark that as an accepted answer.